# Meaning of "but for" as in "But for your support..."

Tags: usage, exam-questions

The following is a question in my book where I am given 3 options from which I have to select one which may improve my question sentence

> In the absence of your support, he would have lost the election.

Options are

1. But for your support he would have lost the election.
2. He would have lost the election, if you had not supported him

I think both of the options are same and I cannot distinguish between them.

Comment: *He does nothing but ask questions* - ***but = except***. In your first example, ***but for = without*** (if he hadn't had your support he would have lost). Both your alternatives are fine, and they mean the same thing, so if that's being presented as a multi-choice test question with only one answer implied to be correct, ***it's a stupid test***.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the meanings are the same.

Sentence 2 has an unnecessary comma. Maybe that's why it's considered wrong.

Sentence 1 is more like the original since the clauses are in the same order, and "But for..." is a direct replacement for "In the absence of..."

Comment: But in my book and on many websites 2 sentence is correct

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=In+absence+of+your+support+he+would+have+lost+the+election&oq=in+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i61l2j69i60l3.1465j0j7&client=ms-android-xiaomi-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @KshitijSingh  I think it's correct too. The comma isn't necessary, but the sentence isn't wrong. But the sentence with "But for..." is still the  better choice.

Comment: Possibly they object to beginning a sentence with 'but'. But I don't have a problem with it.